# C++ Libraries for solving Complex Linear systems Ax=b

Tags: c++, linear-algebra

I am interested in solving a sparse complex linear system Ax=b where A is a square matrix of complex numbers and b is vector of complex numbers.

If possible I would like such a library to be templated (for the ease of installation and use)
sth in the spirit of [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)

I checked out Eigen but it does not, I think,  look like it supports solving linear equations with complex sparse matrices, (although one can create and do elementary operations on complex matrices.)

Another trick someone suggested to me was one can work around this, by solving an extended system of twice the dimension using the fact that (A1 + iA2)(x1 + ix2) = (b1 + ib2)
but I would prefer some simple black box which gets the job done.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/overview.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring it to a real-valued system of twice the dimension might be the most immediate way. You could write an adapter to pack the transformation logic. Also may try this one: http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/docs/r4.0/packages/komplex/doc/html/